# Trouble searching a Stack in Java

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with programming a function in Java.

First i have implemented a `Stack` through a `Single Linked List`, like this:

```
public class ListStack<E> implements Stack<E> {

private static class Node<T> {
    private T item;
    private Node<T> next;

    private Node(T item, Node<T> next) {
        this.item = item;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

private Node<E> first;
private int size;


public ListStack() {
    this.size = 0;
    this.first = null;
}

@Override
public E peek() {
    return first.item;
}

@Override
public void pop() {
    first = first.next;
    size--;
}

@Override
public void push(E e) {

    Node<E> node = new Node<E>(e, first);
    first = node;
    size++;
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {

    return (first == null);
}

@Override
public int size() {

    return size;
}

@Override
public Stack<E> reverse(){

    ListStack<E> reversed = new ListStack<E>();

    Node<E> node = first;

    while(node != null){

      reversed.push(node.item);
      node = node.next;
    }

  return reversed;
  }

}
```

Then i have created a `stack`of a type `X`. Here's that type's definition and constructor:

```
private String first, second;
private ListStack<String> text;

    public X(String first, String second){
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
    this.text = new ListStack<String>();
}
```

There are getters for both the strings `first`and `second`, `getFirst()`, and `getSecond()`, respectively.

Then i want to write a function that basically, for each `X` of the `stack`, checks if the `String second` is equal to the `String` `txt`, passed as the function's argument. If it is, it returns `X` and deletes the Node from the `stack`, otherwise just returns `null`.

Here's my implementation of the method:

First, as a `private` attribute of the class:

```
private Stack<X> text; //for simplicity, let's assume the stack already contains values of type `X`.
```

Then:

```
private X getX(String txt) {

    Stack<X> stack = text.reverse();
    Stack<X> stack_final = new ListStack<X>();

    X c;
    String txt2;
    boolean found = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < stack.size() && !found; i++) {

        c = stack.peek(); //extracts the element
        txt2 = c.getSecond(); //gets the name

        if (txt2.equals(txt)) {
            found = true;
            stack.pop();

        } else
            stack_final.push(c);

        stack.pop();

    }

    if (found) {

        text = stack_final;

        return c;
    }

    else

        return null;

}
```

What am i doing wrong ?

My guess is that i'm not updating the final stack correctly, with only the values that don't check, but i'm not sure it is that...

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?  What actually happens?  I see a bunch of class definitions, but no actual code that puts anything onto the stack.  We can't debug what you don't show us.

Comment: @Teepeemm the logic of the last method is wrong, but i'm having a hard time correcting it. I don't know how to update the final stack in a proper way...

Comment: My understanding is this is not a stack, a stack always removes the top item.         You said -> "Then i want to write a function that basically, for each X of the stack, checks if the String second is equal to the String txt, passed as the function's argument. If it is, it returns X and deletes the Node from the stack, otherwise just returns null."

Comment: By the way, a "stack" should not be searched through.  The entire point of a stack is that you only look and deal with the top element (the next element could be a possible variant).  If you want "getX", then a true stack implementation would destroy everything in the stack until you find "X", and return `null` if you run out of stuff.

Comment: @Teepeemm that's why the first thing i do in the function is create another `stack` that is a copy of the other one, and work with that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get a NullPointerException if you try to `peek()` or `pop()` an empty stack!

```
public E peek() {
    return first.item; // first is null if stack is empty!
}

public void pop() {
    first = first.next; // first is null if stack is empty!
    size--;
}
```

The Java [`Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#peek%28%29) class throws an EmptyStackException in those cases.

> Then I want to write a function that basically, for each X of the stack, checks if the String second is equal to the String txt, passed as the function's argument. If it is, it returns X and deletes the Node from the stack, otherwise just returns null.

Now, to achieve what you asked, you can simply do:

```
Stack<X> stack = text.reversed();
X elementFound = null;
while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
    if (txt.equals(stack.peek().getSecond()) {
        elementFound = stack.peek();
    } else {
        stackCopy.push(stack.peek());
    }
    stack.pop();
}
// now stack is empty and stackCopy contains stack reversed and without
// elementFound, if elementFound is not null (meaning it was found)
text = stackCopy; // stack was text reversed
return elementFound;
```

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is the for-loop. Just step through it in your head:

```
i=0 stack=[1,2,3,4,5,6] stack_size=6
i=1 stack=[2,3,4,5,6] stack_size=5
i=2 stack=[3,4,5,6] stack_size=4
i=3 stack=[4,5,6] stack_size=3
```

the code actually breaks off after reading only half of the stack. You should rather use `isEmpty()` than a counter.

```
private X getX(String txt){
     Stack<X> stack = text.reverse();
     Stack<X> stack_final = new ListStack<X>();

     X c = null;
     while(!stack.isEmpty()){//transfer all items from stack to stack_final
           //retrive and remove the first item from stack 
           X x = stack.peek();
           stack.pop();

           if(x.getSecond().equals(txt))//save x as searched item, if it matches
                 c = x;

           //add the item to stack_final
           stack_final.push(x);
      }

      //save stack_final as text (stack_final is a copy of text)
      text = stack_final;

      //c is either the searched item, or null, if no item was found
      return c;
 }
```

And btw., it's common that `pop()` returns the removed element.

```
public X pop(){
    X res = first.item;

    first = first.next;

    return res;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a null pointer exception on the last `stack.pop()`. Perhaps it is trying to pop something that does not exist, how can i fix it ?

Comment: if the last item of your stack matches the conditions, you call `stack.pop()` twice, which results in the nullpointer exception. but you have some other issues aswell. you're code doesn't only search, but also modify the stack. text will always have a different content after running your search.

Comment: Can you explain the code ? because it's not making a lot of sense to me

Comment: i've added some comments to explain the stuff. and an example for the more common implementation of pop

Comment: yes but that is wrong, because i'm supposed to delete  `x` from the stack if it matches, and then return a new stack without the matched element

Comment: i've taken another look at your code. your class X itself is a bit strange. and you cant access private fields of the superclass, so you'll have a bit of a problem with your code. this code is overall a bit messy.

Comment: try to reorganize the code. especially the implementation of X.